# is there a way to workaround closing of file descriptor cretaed using pipe function

Tags: c, linux, pipe

I want to know whether we can actually create a workaround/alias for closing of file descriptor. Meaning, close(fd) should do something internal to the stream associated with the fd (file descriptor). Can we attain/provide that functionality of close function without actually using the close function on file descriptor.

I want this in scenario where i dont want to close write end of pipe (created using pipe() function), but the other end shouldn't be aware of this. The other end of pipe should feel like the opposite end is actually closed.

Comment: Can you explain why you need to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you're looking for the `shutdown` function. But that is used for full duplex connections to indicate that the data is ending in one direction.

Maybe a unidirectional pipe can be shut down for writing with `shutdown` from the write end? Never heard of this being done.

That would be the closest thing to manipulating the state of a connection in a way that resembles closing, without actually disposing of the file descriptor. (If that operation is possible on these objects.)

You go ahead and be the guinea pig. ;)

Comment: `shutdown` operates on sockets, not pipes.

Comment: @kaz: can we use shutdown function on pipes??? as one of our friends mentioned that it cant be used with pipes

Answer (score 0):

"If you create an externally-visible function with the same name
as a system function, *your* function will be called _instead_of_ the
original system function.  "

```
#include<stdio.h>
int open(const char *p,int f) {
    printf("we are in our open()\n");
}
int close() {
    printf("we are in our close()\n");
}

main() {
    open("test",1);
    close();
    return 0;
}
```

[Picked from here](http://fixunix.com/unix/353470-intercepting-system-calls-linux.html)